# stderr to /dev/tty12 for good

Tags: unix

I want to redirect persistently stderr to /dev/tty12 so error messages do not touch my nerves when doing something in tty1.

The redirection should go through init.d or ~/.bashrc or ~./bash_profile. Just once.

Can it be done and how?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a really bad idea, and I doubt that the system provides a way to do it.

Whenever a process is created, the calling process determines where its stdin, stdout, and stderr will be directed. There would have to be a general way to override that -- and it would break any mechanisms that redirect stderr explicitly.

For example, if you type:

```
some_command >some_command.out 2>some_command.err
```

should `some_command`'s stderr go to `some_command.err`, or to `/dev/tty12`?

The closest thing I can think of is to invoke a shell with its stderr redirected:

```
bash -l 2>/dev/tty12
```

In my (brief) experiments (redirecting to a file rather than to a tty), this causes the shell to be non-interactive.  Adding `-i` forces it to be interactive -- but the shell prompt is apparently printed to stderr.

Of course you can redirect stderr for individual commands (assuming you're not using `csh` or `tcsh`):

```
some_command 2>some_command.err
```

and you could define a shell function that does this for you:

```
e() { "$@" 2>/dev/tty12 ; }
```

Then, for each command whose stderr you want redirected, just prepend `e` to the command:

```
e some_command
```

Answer (score 0):

Many shells write their interactive prompts to stderr, so you are likely to have trouble interacting with a shell if you redirect it's stderr to `/dev/tty12`.  Also, error messages are important.  Why ignore them?